# PHP Array Initialize

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have a PHP array of arrays.

I am testing to see if an index is set or not. If false I want to initialise the given index so it is an empty set, something like:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['temp'][$_POST['theindex']]) ){

          $_SESSION['temp'][$_POST['theindex']]=array();

}
```

Do I have to implicitly specify the structure of the array or can I have it copy the structure of the other arrays which are in the index?

Thanks

Comment: Of course you have to, otherwise how would PHP know which index should be used ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `structure of the array`? There are 4 arrays mentioned in the code above.

Comment: by structure of the array I meant the index names used in the other arrays stored in the array. I can see that I do have to implicitly create the array to be stored now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to implicitly specify the structure of the array or can I have it copy the structure of the other arrays which are in the index?

I am afraid it's impossible to copy the only structure, without data.
So, if you have an empty reference array - why not to use it to inialize?

Comment: Yes it makes sense now, because an array of array could be of different structures. I guess if I wanted to have a fixed structure I would have to create my own object in order to achieve that goal...